# What is the best way to implement Singleton pattern combined with Factory pattern in Java? Detail in description

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, factory-pattern

I am learning design patterns for JAVA. I wanted to use factory pattern with singleton. Now I am not sure If I went with correct approach or not.

Let me share what I have tried first. 
I have used Button as example class. Aim is to get singleInstance of Button and then get it's color. Can anyone let me know if it's usable in actual implementation? Am I missing on anything or on a better approach?

Here's my code:

**`Button.java`**

```
public abstract class Button {
    abstract void getButton();
}
```

**`ButtonClientClass.java`**

```
public class ButtonClientClass {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Button red = ButtonFactory.getButton("RedButton");
    red.getButton();
    System.out.println("hashcode"+red.hashCode());
    Button red2 = ButtonFactory.getButton("RedButton");
    System.out.println("hashcode"+red2.hashCode());

    Button green = ButtonFactory.getButton("GreenButton");
    green.getButton();
    System.out.println("hashcode"+green.hashCode());
    Button green2= ButtonFactory.getButton("GreenButton");
    System.out.println("hashcode"+green2.hashCode());
}
}
```

**`ButtonFactory.java`**

```
public class ButtonFactory {
public static Button getButton(String button){
    if(button.equals("RedButton")){
        return RedButton.getSingleRedButton();      
    }else{
        return GreenButton.getSingleGreenButton();
    }
}
}
```

**`GreenButton.java`**

```
public class GreenButton extends Button{

    private static class GreenButtonHolder {
        public static GreenButton INSTANCE = new GreenButton();
    }
    private GreenButton(){}
    public static GreenButton getSingleGreenButton(){
        return GreenButtonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
    @Override
    void getButton() {
    System.out.println("You have a GreenButton");   
    }
}
```

**`RedButton.java`**

```
public class RedButton extends Button{
    private static class RedButtonHolder{
        public static RedButton INSTANCE = new RedButton();
    }
    private RedButton(){ }
    public static RedButton getSingleRedButton(){
        return RedButtonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
    @Override
    void getButton() {
        System.out.println("You have a RedButton"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the abstract method `getButton()` the only method in a `Button`? Are there any instance fields?

Comment: Yes, it's usable, although quite a bit overcomplex. You could have the factory return buttons from a `Map<String, Button>`.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes. For now, It's the only one, without any instance fields. I am just learning by doing. I hope to add more though.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik What do you mean by overcomplex in this context? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: As I said, you don't need the static singletons. Instead build a Map<String, Button> that contains all the simgletons and have the factory method fetch them from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `enum` is the simplest way to implement singleton. JVM will ensure the instance is only one without any necessary effort. That's why it's also safer way.
Your example could looks like:

**`Button.java`**

```
public interface Button {
    void printButton();
}
```

**`GreenButton.java`**

```
public enum GreenButton implements Button {
    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public void printButton() {
        System.out.println("Green button");
    }
}
```

**`RedButton.java`**

```
public enum RedButton implements Button {
    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public void getButton() {
        System.out.println("Red button");
    }
}
```

**`ButtonFactory.java`**

```
public ButtonFactory {

    /*
    * In such situation, where you select one from few states (like you do for colors)
    * it's also better to use enum instead of String. It's more convenient to reuse your code. 
    */
    public static Button getButton(ButtonType type) {
        if (type == ButtonType.GREEN)
            return GreenButton.INSTANCE;
        if (type == ButtonType.RED)
            return RedButton.INSTANCE;
    }

    public static enum ButtonType {
        GREEN, RED;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is baroque. All you need is `enum Button { GREEN { @Override public void getButton() { .. }, RED { @Override public void getButton() { ... } }`

Answer (score 2):

Enums are singletons, so:

```
public enum Button {
    RedButton() {
        public void doSomething() {
            // whatever
        }
    },
    GreenButton() {
        public void doSomething() {
            // whatever else
        }
    };
    public void getButton() {
        System.out.println("You have a " + name());
    }
    public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

Enums can have fields too, and in most ways are just like a normal class. Their main restriction is that they can't extend classes, but can implement interfaces.

Comment: In that case you have `Button` which has 2 instances: `RedButton` and `GreenButton`  so it's not singleton anymore.

Comment: @JakubCh. Each enum instance (eg RedButton) is a singleton, guaranteed by the JVM

Comment: Yeah, I know that `RedButton` and `GreenButton` are the only instances of `Button` guaranteed by JVM, I agree with you. But Singleton Pattern stands for one instance per class. In you example `Button` is such a class and `RedButton` and  `GreenButton` are its instances. You see my point?

Comment: Example is good enough for the whole situation, but let's change a context. Let's assume that `RedButton` and `GreenButton` should have different behaviour. You couldn't provide different behaviour in such an implementation, could you?

Comment: @JakubCh. Yes, you could. Each enum member can be an instance of its own private subclass of the enum class.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True. I missed that.

Comment: @jak I've added a method to the enum that each instance has its own impl for. You can add getters, functions and even setters too. Whatever you need.